# Google says requestLegacyExternalStorage flag is detected, but my app doesn't use it

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-10.0, android-external-storage, android-11

I'm receiving this email in apps compiled with api 29 and api 30.

These apps **does not contains** `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag and **does not contains** `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

I already searched in manifest merger log, and in the final merged manifest, and didn't found `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag inside.

These apps only have the old and deprecated `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Is that old and deprecated permission which is firing that warning from google? is enough with removing that permission from my apps to get this issue solved?

> Starting May 5th, you must let us know why your app requires broad
> storage access
>
> We've detected that your app contains the
> `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag in the `manifest` file of 1 or more of
> your app bundles or APKs.
>
> Developers with apps on devices running **Android 11+** must use Scoped
> Storage to give users better access control over their device storage.
> To release your app on **Android 11** or newer after May 5th, you must
> either:
>
> Update your app to use more privacy friendly best practices, such as
> the Storage Access `Framework` or `Media Store API`
>
> Update your app to declare the All files access
> (`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) permission in the manifest file, and
> complete the All files access permission declaration in Play Console
> from May 5th
>
> Remove the All files access permission from your app entirely
>
> For apps targeting **Android 11**, the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag
> will be ignored. You must use the All files access permission to
> retain broad access.
>
> Apps requesting access to the All files access permission without a
> permitted use will be removed from **Google Play**, and you won't be able
> to publish updates.

Comment: @tyczj I already searched in manifest merger log, and in the final merged manifest, and didn't found requestLegacyExternalStorageflag inside. Is that enough to be sure?

Comment: The flag name is actually `requestLegacyExternalStorage`

Comment: @fillobotto yes I know, corrected, thanks

Comment: Maybe a library you use does it?

Comment: @blackapps I already searched in manifest merger log, and in the final merged manifest, and didn't found requestLegacyExternalStorage flag inside. Is that enough to be sure?

Comment: Same for us, we received this notification but we don't use this flag for release builds. On downloading the APK from Google Play Console and checking the manifest file, it has no requestLegacyExternalStorage

Comment: @IslamSalah did you have the old and deprecated WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? or did you receive the warning without thar permission in your manifest?

Comment: @NullPointerException Yes we have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` but we neither have `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` nor `requestLegacyExternalStorage`. Any findings?

Comment: @IslamSalah did you know if after removing WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  those warnings dissapear? I don't have any findings now

Comment: @NullPointerException do you have any updates on this?

Comment: @eden no, nothing

Comment: @IslamSalah did you have that flag in the past? maybe do you have two versions alive of your app in the store, one with the flag and one without the flag?

Comment: @eden the same for you, did you have that flag in the past? maybe do you have two versions alive of your app in the store, one with the flag and one without the flag?

Comment: @NullPointerException nope, but as far as I can tell from reading other people's comments on this issue, this might be just a simple "heads up" notice from Google